# Beautiful Soup HTML parser is not working correctly on this website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

URL Link" https://www.fitchratings.com/search/?expanded=racs&filter.country=&filter.language=English&filter.region=&filter.sector=&filter.sector=Structured%20Finance%3A%20RMBS&filter.topic=&isIdentifier=true&page=1&viewType=data

I am trying to get the `DATE`, `TITLE`, `TYPE`, `SECTOR`, `COUNTRY`, `ANALYST(S)` by web scrapping using beautiful soup.

I am trying to scrape data by looking at 'inspect element'

But when I look at the 'inspect element' vs 'view Page Source', no data is visible in 'view Page Source'

Similarly when I am using "page_html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html.content, 'html.parser')", the content that I get do not have any relevant data.

My code is mentioned below:

```
'''
global fitch_rating_database
fitch_rating_database = []

base_url = "https://www.fitchratings.com/search?expanded=racs&filter.country=&filter.language=English&filter.region=&filter.sector=&filter.sector=Structured%20Finance%3A%20RMBS&filter.topic=&isIdentifier=true&viewType=data&page="

for i in range(1,24):

    print(i)
    i=str(i)


    url = "%s%s"%(base_url,i)

    print(url)
    
# Set up the Selenium driver (in this case I am using the Chrome browser)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options) 

    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.get(url) #driver.get is used to open the URL in the web browser

    page_html = get(url) #we will request from the server the content of the web page (html) by using get()
    time.sleep(10)
    
    page_html_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html.content, 'html.parser')
    
    # print(page_html_soup)
    
    articles = page_html_soup.find_all('div', class_='column__five column__wrapper--1 column--merge-a article-data')
    
    for article in articles:
        title = article.find("a", class_="column article-data--title").text.strip()
        article_type = article.find("span", class_="column article-data--type").text.strip()
        analyst = article.find("p", class_="column article-data--analyst").text.strip()
        
        print("Title:", title)
        print("Type:", article_type)
        print("Analyst:", analyst)
        print()
    

        fitch_rating_database.append([title, article_type, analyst])
      


print("\nDone")
driver.close()
driver.quit()    


fitch_rating_database = pd.DataFrame(fitch_rating_database,columns=["Title", "Type", "Analyst"])
'''
```

Looking forward to a solution to this. Is it possible that this website cannot be scraped?

Answer (score 0):

This page is driven by javascript. Essentially, there is a small payload that loads a bunch of javascript. That javascript loads more stuff then actually adds the content to the page.

These pages are more complicated to parse. Options include

1. You are using selenium, so you can try to add `WaitForElementPresent` on the selector you desire. Many websites add anti-scraping detection that prevents headless browsers from interacting with it.
2. Work with a scraping tool that runs a headless browser for you and circumvents common mitigations for scraping protections. There are many out there, and they are relatively cheap. I am not affiliated, but something like this would work https://www.scrapingbee.com/
3. Another trick you can do is to write a javascript function that will do everything for you in chrome and save all of the outputs into a large JSON blob that you can then parse locally. I have done this before for a quick and hacky scrape job.